# Vista like Search box in Windows Xp

Tags: windows-xp, search

How do i get a Windows Vista like [Search box](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/The-Start-menu-overview) in Windows Xp. There's a program here : [http://www.vistastartmenu.com](http://www.vistastartmenu.com/)/ . What are the other ?

Comment: If you are interested by the **program launcher** facet, you will find a list of programs doing this task at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/5439/must-have-launcher-applications

Comment: If interested by the **search files** facet, you will find a list of programs at this other question: http://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows

Comment: If you want specifically a program which is doing both, and placing this Search box in the start menu, however, this is a different question for which you won't find an answer on the given links.

Comment: i'm interested in the program launcher

Comment: In this case your question is a duplicate, and you will find your answers on the first link I gave. However, instead of closing your question as a duplicate, I propose we specialize it, only for "I need the exact same functionality on XP, including the look and feel".

Comment: yes I would agree to that

Comment: I just need the Integrated Start Menu Searc

Comment: @iceman: Might I ask that you edit your question to include the added detail? It will better benefit readers, rather than forcing them to read all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**ViStart**](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/)

> Launch Programs faster then ever
>   before
>
> ViStart dramatically decreases the
>   time taken to search for programs by
>   indexing your program shortcuts. Then
>   you can simply type part of the
>   program into the start menu and
>   ViStart will "instantly" find it.
>
> Find files faster then Vista
>
> ViStart not only indexes programs but
>   also files as well. Just type the file
>   you are looking for and in miliseconds
>   ViStart will return results (Up to 4
>   times faster then the orignal Vista
>   start menu!).
>
> Microsoft Vista skin
>
> ViStart includes a skin that looks
>   exactly like the Windows Vista's start
>   menu and it also supports 3rd party
>   skins. A wide range of skins made by
>   ViStart fans are available through
>   deviantart.
>
> Fading Menu Icons
>
> As you roll over each option on the
>   menu ViStart will blend each option
>   just like Vista's icons.
>
> Multilanguage support
>
> ViStart supports natively English,
>   Japanese, German, French, Italian,
>   Russian, Korean, Chinese and Dutch.

[image]

Comment: just tried ViStart..the search box just above the windows logo doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

Micrososoft Windows Search:
You can get it for Windows XP here:
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4.mspx?tab=Install%20It

Comment: Yup, MS Search 4.0 is the way to do so..

Answer (score -1):

Just use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). Much more effective, much faster, so much better than the XP/Vista/Windows 7 search tool. Just give it a try.

Comment: Not fitting the need, though.